# Reset time counter on start using jquery

Tags: jquery, timer, counter

I want to start time counter on start button by using jQuery.

My code is working fine but when I click on start button two or three times it runs fast instead of normal running. My need is when I click on start button it reset time and start again counter. In this code reset button is working fine but I wish it completely works by start button click.

Here's code

```js
var interval;
var minutes = 5;
var seconds = 10;

function countdown(element) {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById(element);
    if (seconds == 0) {
      if (minutes == 0) {
        alert(el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!");
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      } else {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 60;
      }
    }
    if (minutes > 0) {
      var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
    } else {
      var minute_text = '';
    }
    var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
    el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
    seconds--;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id='countdown'></div>
<input type="button" onclick="countdown('countdown');" value="Start" />
<input type="button" onclick="minutes=5;seconds=10;" value="Reset" />
```

Comment: `function countdown(element) { clearInterval(interval); 
  interval = setInterval(function() {`

Comment: Voting to close as _Caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Also note that it's *much* easier to just work in seconds. That way you just decrement one value and format it to hours/minutes/seconds only when it's displayed

Comment: @mplungjan i used your logic but i want to restart it again start button. when i clicked start again it should reset previous time and start from given time.

Comment: So start countdown on reset too

Comment: could you please make a demo ?

Comment: if once time over it not work on start button or reset button. i m newbie

Comment: I’ll look later